# How can I rigorously explain that these two complex integrals 'cancel out'?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve this integral;

> Where $\psi$ is the ellipse centered at the origin, with
> parameterisation $(4\cos(t), \sin(t))$: $$\int_\psi \frac{\tan(\pi z)}{z^2} dz$$

Let's call the integrand $\phi(z)$. I'm aware of a few points on and in the contour where $\phi$ is not defined:
$$\{0, 1/2,-1/2\}$$

To 'dodge' them, I applied the deformation theorem to turn the ellipse into a curve made up of three little circles centered at these points, with radii small enough as to be contained in the original interior and not intersect each other. ***I hope this is a correct application of the theorem.***

I then *split* the circles into their own curves, which I will call $a$, $b$, $c$, respectively centered at $-1/2$, $0$ and $1/2$.

> For $b$ I noticed that we have $(z - 0)^2$ in the denominator and the rest is holomorphic, hence
> applied Cauchy's Integral Formula to obtain $2i \pi^2$. This agrees with the answer!
>
> For $a$ and $c$, I pointed out that the integrand is an odd function, and that whatever the value over $a$ is, it must be the negative of $c$ since they're equally far from the origin. *I don't like this explanation... I feel like it can be improved.*

Something that comes to mind that might help is the fact that reversing the curve negates the integral. However I'm unsure if it applies, or if it does, how to apply it to this case where $a$ and $b$ are not the same curve, and both positively oriented.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: It seems that if we consider $a$ and $b$ as sets of points, then $a = -b$ and so we're integrating the same integrand, once over $a$ and once over $-a$ which we can rewrite as the negation of the integral of $a$. Is this correct? (This is of course assuming they're both of the same radius)

Comment: The deformation theorem should be accurately applied. The intuition here is that the curves when going from a circle that encompasses all three to three separate circles is that it should look like an animation of cell division.